# XCode App Crashes, Help Debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, error-handling, parse-platform

I am building a simple iPhone app that utilizes Parse as a login to get into the system. Whenever I click the register button on the register view (which simply just has textfields that get submitted to parse) the whole app crashes. It always does so on that register button. Fairly new to iphone development, I am having a hard time discovering what the cause of this is. Usually there is some sort of error printed in the logs, and within a few google searches I can fix it.. here is my log..

```
    2015-01-10 07:41:20.475 Pac18[325:a0b] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-01-10 07:41:20.507 Pac18[325:a0b] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-01-10 07:41:20.695 Pac18[325:a0b] Going To Login Controller
2015-01-10 07:41:22.613 Pac18[325:a0b] Register Button has been Hit
Jan 10 07:41:27 Joes-Mac.local Pac18[325] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

(The last line repeats about 50 times)

If you guys have any advice on debugging this or the process I should go about to solve this. Usually I find that it says why the app is crashing...

UPDATE: HERE IS THE CODE of the view controller that the app crashes on

```
#import "LogInViewController.h"
#import "JVFloatLabeledTextField.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"

@interface LogInViewController ()

@end

@implementation LogInViewController

@synthesize inputAccessoryView, inputView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.registerView.hidden = YES;

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {
    //logs in user into the app..
        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_loginUsernameField.text password:_loginPasswordField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *loginError) {        if (!loginError) {
            //this means there wasn't an error
            _loginPasswordField.text = nil;
            _loginUsernameField.text = nil;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logontomain" sender:self];
            NSLog(@"Succesfully Logged in User");
        }
            if (loginError) {
                //there was an error logging in :(
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ooops!" message:@"Sorry we had a problem logging you in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            }
            }];
}

- (IBAction)registerButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Register Button has been Hit");
//hides one view and creates the other
    self.loginView.hidden = YES;
    self.registerView.hidden = NO;
}
- (IBAction)submitRegistation:(id)sender {
    [_registrationEmail resignFirstResponder];
    [_registrationUsername resignFirstResponder];
    [_registrationPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [_registrationPassword2 resignFirstResponder];

    //now we run the "Check Fields Complete"
    //checks to see if all the filled out fields are complete

    //[self 1checkRegistrationFieldsComplete];
    [self registerNewUser];
}
/*
- (void) 1checkRegistrationFieldsComplete {
    if (![_registrationPassword2.text isEqualToString:_registrationPassword2.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oooopss!" message:@"Passwords don't match" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }
    else {
        [self registerNewUser];
        //now that that stuff is complete and the passwords match, lets register the new guy
    }
                                      };
*/


- (void) registerNewUser {

        NSLog(@"Now Registering the User");
        PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
        newUser.username = _registrationUsername.text;
        newUser.email = _registrationEmail.text;
        newUser.password = _registrationPassword.text;

        [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Registration Successful!");
                _registrationPassword.text = nil;
                _registrationEmail.text = nil;
                _registrationPassword2.text = nil;
                _registrationEmail.text = nil;
                _loginPasswordField.text = nil;
                _loginUsernameField.text = nil;

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logontomain" sender:self];
                //after we are done registering this basically
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"There was an error in Registration");
            }

        }];

}




/*
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationUsername;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationEmail;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationPassword;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationPassword2;
 */
@end

Here is the .H code as well


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JVFloatLabeledTextField.h"
#import "JVFloatLabeledTextView.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BSKeyboardControls.h"

@interface LogInViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, BSKeyboardControlsDelegate>

//the action buttons.. letting you log in or not
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)registerButton:(id)sender;


//these are the login fields 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *loginUsernameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *loginPasswordField;

//i hide the views to change from registration to login
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loginView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *registerView;


//Registration Fields
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationUsername;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationEmail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationPassword;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JVFloatLabeledTextField *registrationPassword2;

- (IBAction)submitRegistation:(id)sender;

@property (readonly, retain) UIView *inputView;
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that gets called when you hit the button?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! See the original post I just added the .h as well as the .m source code :D

Comment: I try to go line by line by using break points to see if I can figure out which line causes the crash. One thing I noticed is that you are importing parse as a file with "" rather than as a library with <>. Not sure that matters though.

Comment: Hmm tried changing that. Everytime it highlights a method I call and says its the breakpoint? is that the cause of the crash?